# Submit doesn`t work in Form component from Shadcn in Next14 project

Tags: next.js13, react-hook-form, shadcnui

I try to use Form component from Shadcn and take an example from docs. I create a form and async function for it`s submitting, but when I click submit button the function doesn`t call. I have no any errors in console and terminal. Why it may happens and how I can fix it?

I try to use not async function, but it also doesn`t work. It`s look like the function isn`t called at all, because I don`t see even console.log within it. But I do all that are in docs.

This is the code of the component:

```
"use client";

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";
import { MinistrySchema } from "@/lib/validations";
// import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";

import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import Image from "next/image";
import { addMinistry } from "@/lib/actions/ministry.action";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const type: any = "create";

interface Props {
  mongoUserId: string;
}

const AddMinistryForm = ({ mongoUserId }: Props) => {
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  //   const pathname = usePathname();

  // 1. Define your form.
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof MinistrySchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(MinistrySchema),
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      chiefName: "",
      chiefLastName: "",
        chiefPhoto: "",
        team: [],
        gallery: [],
      purpose: "",
      phone: "",
    },
  });

  // 2. Define a submit handler.
  async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof MinistrySchema>) {
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    console.log("jfhdjfhdjh");

    try {
      await addMinistry({
        title: values.title,
        description: values.description,
        chiefName: values.chiefName,
        chiefLastName: values.chiefLastName,
        chiefPhoto: "",
        team: [],
        gallery: [],
        purpose: values.purpose,
        phone: values.phone,
      });

      router.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className="flex w-full flex-col gap-10"
      >
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="title"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="flex w-full flex-col">
              <FormLabel className="paragraph-semibold text-dark400_light800">
                Question Title <span className="text-primary-500">*</span>
              </FormLabel>
              <FormControl className="mt-3.5">
                <Input
                  className="no-focus paragraph-regular background-light900_dark300 light-border-2 text-dark300_light700 min-h-[56px] border"
                  {...field}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormDescription className="body-regular mt-2.5 text-light-500">
                Be specific and imagine you&apos;re asking a question to another
                person.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage className="text-red-500" />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        {/* <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="title"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="flex w-full flex-col">
              <FormLabel className="paragraph-semibold text-dark400_light800">
                Question Title <span className="text-primary-500">*</span>
              </FormLabel>
              <FormControl className="mt-3.5">
                <Input
                  className="no-focus paragraph-regular background-light900_dark300 light-border-2 text-dark300_light700 min-h-[56px] border"
                  {...field}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormDescription className="body-regular mt-2.5 text-light-500">
                Be specific and imagine you&apos;re asking a question to another
                person.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage className="text-red-500" />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        /> */}
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="description"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="flex w-full flex-col">
              <FormLabel className="paragraph-semibold text-dark400_light800">
                Question Title <span className="text-primary-500">*</span>
              </FormLabel>
              <FormControl className="mt-3.5">
                <Input
                  className="no-focus paragraph-regular background-light900_dark300 light-border-2 text-dark300_light700 min-h-[56px] border"
                  {...field}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormDescription className="body-regular mt-2.5 text-light-500">
                Be specific and imagine you&apos;re asking a question to another
                person.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage className="text-red-500" />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="chiefName"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="flex w-full flex-col">
              <FormLabel className="paragraph-semibold text-dark400_light800">
                Question Title <span className="text-primary-500">*</span>
              </FormLabel>
              <FormControl className="mt-3.5">
                <Input
                  className="no-focus paragraph-regular background-light900_dark300 light-border-2 text-dark300_light700 min-h-[56px] border"
                  {...field}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormDescription className="body-regular mt-2.5 text-light-500">
                Be specific and imagine you&apos;re asking a question to another
                person.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage className="text-red-500" />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="chiefLastName"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="flex w-full flex-col">
              <FormLabel className="paragraph-semibold text-dark400_light800">
                Question Title <span className="text-primary-500">*</span>
              </FormLabel>
              <FormControl className="mt-3.5">
                <Input
                  className="no-focus paragraph-regular background-light900_dark300 light-border-2 text-dark300_light700 min-h-[56px] border"
                  {...field}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormDescription className="body-regular mt-2.5 text-light-500">
                Be specific and imagine you&apos;re asking a question to another
                person.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage className="text-red-500" />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="purpose"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="flex w-full flex-col">
              <FormLabel className="paragraph-semibold text-dark400_light800">
                Question Title <span className="text-primary-500">*</span>
              </FormLabel>
              <FormControl className="mt-3.5">
                <Input
                  className="no-focus paragraph-regular background-light900_dark300 light-border-2 text-dark300_light700 min-h-[56px] border"
                  {...field}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormDescription className="body-regular mt-2.5 text-light-500">
                Be specific and imagine you&apos;re asking a question to another
                person.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage className="text-red-500" />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="phone"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="flex w-full flex-col">
              <FormLabel className="paragraph-semibold text-dark400_light800">
                Question Title <span className="text-primary-500">*</span>
              </FormLabel>
              <FormControl className="mt-3.5">
                <Input
                  className="no-focus paragraph-regular background-light900_dark300 light-border-2 text-dark300_light700 min-h-[56px] border"
                  {...field}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormDescription className="body-regular mt-2.5 text-light-500">
                Be specific and imagine you&apos;re asking a question to another
                person.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage className="text-red-500" />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />

        <Button
          type="submit"
          className="primary-gradient z-50 w-fit !text-light-900"
          disabled={isSubmitting}
          onClick={() => console.log("Button clicked")}
        >
          {isSubmitting ? (
            <>{type === "edit" ? "Editing..." : "Posting..."}</>
          ) : (
            <>{type === "edit" ? "Edit Question" : "Ask a Question"}</>
          )}
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default AddMinistryForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong in your schema, comment out that part and try again:

```js
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof MinistrySchema>>({
   // resolver: zodResolver(MinistrySchema),
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      chiefName: "",
      chiefLastName: "",
        chiefPhoto: "",
        team: [],
        gallery: [],
      purpose: "",
      phone: "",
    },
  });
```

Comment: I tried to do it, but it still doesn't work